When creating a new app with angular .... does the npm installation require internet access?
when I create new angular apps, the npm installation seems to run faster if I use an internet connection ... I just want to know if this is a coincidence or not and if there are faster ways to create apps with angular
I tried creating them without an  internet connection but it didnt' finish even after three long hours

Yes, you need internet connection to install NPM packages from NPM registry, however If you don't have a stable internet connection and you need to work offline you can check this one - How to install npm package while offline?
